# What is the appropriate way to add tab key in tinyMCE?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tabs

I have tinyMCE editor in my page.

Browser itself have different behavior for tab, shift + tab, ctrl + tab, ctrl + shift + tab. Currently on tab press tinyMCE editor will make a indent space. So i need to add focus out for the editor with any of the options above.

Which is the best combination to add that funtionality?

Comment: I don't understands what's the problem.

Comment: @Seth I need a suggestion from experienced developer whether i can give focusout on tab press while tab key is currently using for adding indent.

Comment: Is that a JS event? If so StackOverflow would be more appropriate. Maybe [this](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/tabfocus/) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543220/tiny-mce-how-to-allow-people-to-indent) could be what you're looking for? Usually having Tab actually insert one requires some settings.

Answer (score 0):

For those stumbling onto this ancient page, see https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/tabfocus/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).